# ¿Cómo puedo mandar notificaciones con la aplicación cerrada en Windows Forms C#?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, windows

Tengo una aplicación de Windows Forms para Windows. Es una aplicación de alarma.

En el formulario 1 (formulario principal) hay 2 datetimepicker y 2 botones. El datetimepicker 1 está vinculado con el botón 1. Cuando presiona el botón 1 debe enviarle una notificación (con el control de notificación: NotifyIcon) y el otro datetimepicker y el botón 2 son para el mismo, sólo una segunda alarma.

Eso es todo lo que he intentado y todo lo que sé. El problema ahora es que no puedo enviar las notificaciones con la aplicación cerrada, que básicamente es el propósito de la aplicación. Lo único que supongo que podría hacer es crear otro hilo o algo similar, pero que funcione como una tarea normal, en segundo plano, como las que podrías cancelar en el administrador de tareas.

[image: Este es el formulario principal]

Comment: Hola @SergioMarquez, bienvenid@ a Stack Overflow, te sugiero completar el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que te familiarices con el funcionamiento del lugar y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. También puedes revisar la sección de [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas respuestas de calidad.

Comment: Tienes varias posibilidades, crear un hilo que muera al acabar el tiempo(No lo dejes vivo para matarlo desde el Administrador de Tareas queda feo),minimizar la aplicacion en lugar de cerrarla o crear un servicio

Comment: lo que necesitas es crearte un aplicación de servicio de windows, y gestionarla como tal. Te dejo un enlace con información: https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/framework/windows-services/introduction-to-windows-service-applications